# Chrome doesn't render box-shadow and border-radius properly,when both are applied,is there a fix for this?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I applied box-shadow and border-radius property to a input box ,
here are the effects in chrome and firefox,

[image]

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

This was a known bug fixed about 2 weeks ago in Chromium dev channel http://paulirish.com/2011/chrome-inset-box-shadow-bug-fixed/

Comment: so there is no fix for the older version ?,the ones prior to 10

Comment: not that I know of. But given Chrome's schedule to release a new version every 6 weeks, Chrome stable should reach version 10 in about 2-3 months. and since chrome auto-updates, users should have that version immediately

Answer (score 0):

are you using -webkit-box-shadow to target webkit browsers (chrome, safari and others)?

see:
http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nightly Chrome Updater extension for chrome, to download latest version of browser (containing fix for this bug).

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/akabngbddgpigiemjhkblleffkbpmpfc

You can download it as a zip file too, thus not requiring to install it , and not messing around  installed version.